# How do I exclude a single directory from HTTPS to HTTP 301 redirect with IIS6+IIRF

Tags: iis-6, iirf

I already have a 301 from `HTTPS` to `HTTP` sitewide.
But I want to exclude checkout pages so that they are always `HTTPS` (located in "/shopping-cart/")

Tried this:

```
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
#RedirectRule ^/shopping-cart(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shopping-cart$1 [R=301]
```

This gives me a redirect loop when I get to `/shopping-cart/` pages

Answer (score 0):

What I think is causing the loop is the sequence of the rules. Swap them and add the `[l]` tag to the `shopping_cart` rule (the `[l]` means "last" i.e. stop processing further rules if this rule matches)

```
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
#RedirectRule ^/shopping-cart(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shopping-cart$1 [R=301, l]

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]
```